# What is Ubuntu Global Jam?

Tags: events

[image: Ubuntu Global Jam 2012]

I keep seeing the above image here on the Ask Ubuntu and I'm curious to know what **Ubuntu Global Jam** is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Global Jam is an Ubuntu community event.  It is mainly to encourage mass bug reporting and fixing.  The event is however not limited to bugs, you can also contribute in the form of Translations, Development, Design, Testing, Packaging, Documentation and Promotion.

They encourage you to get together and contribute with other people.  People tend to just conduct sessions in IRC chat however meeting up is encouraged.  Information for what [LoCo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeams) teams are doing can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGlobalJam/Events).  If you want to know about setting up your own Jam, then look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Jams).

See more:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGlobalJam